# Is it possible to integrate braintree with .net desktop application?

Tags: braintree

Is it possible to integrate braintree payment gateway with .net desktop application rather than Website, And Mobile applications? As per their documentation, they have three Client SDKs (JS, Android, IOS).

Answer (score 0):

For it to be secure you should have an HTTPS web service handling the server-side portion of the Braintree integration. This server does not need to serve any HTML. It does need to handle the server-side API communication with Braintree servers, and send the token to the client when requested, and receive the nonce from the client and use it to create transactions.

The "desktop" client .NET application should use the JS SDK. Theoretically the client could implement HTTPS calls in native .NET with no JS SDK, but it will be far simpler and more robust to use the JS SDK provided by Braintree in your .NET application.

Comment: Server side is completed now. But, my application is not Asp.net but c#.net desktop application. How would I use JS SDK? Kindly suggest.

Comment: There are very many ways to render HTML/JS using a desktop application, either internally or externally to it. I will let you do the research and find the way that works best for you.

Comment: But, since you need a server anyway for the braintree server side, the most straightforward way is probably to have the HTML/JS payment form hosted on there somewhere, and just open an embedded window to that payment flow within your desktop application